# Help using an array in 'exclude' key of another array

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, array

I want to exclude two items (using their IDs) from an array that's retrieving images attached to the post: the post's thumbnail (featured image) and an image attached via Advanced Custom Fields.

I'm getting the first one's ID using `get_post_thumbnail_id()` and this last one's ID using `get_field_object('icon')`, where `'icon'` is the `$selector` of the custom field (essentially an image, that's being used as an icon). If you're not familiar with ACF's Documentation the relevant part about this is [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/).

I've scrapped everything irrelevant for demonstration purposes. This is what I have and where [I believe] my problem is at:

```
$var = get_children(array(
  'exclude' => array(
    get_post_thumbnail_id(),
    get_field_object('icon')['ID'])
));
```

I'm thinking the result of `get_post_thumbnail_id` is an integer, so it works perfectly, but the result of `get_field_object['ID']` is a string and that's why it doesn't work. If I could use something like `echo` it would probably work.

I would love to understand where it's wrong and how to make this work, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use wrong ACF function.

`get_field_object` returns the settings of a specific field. Each field contains many settings such as a label, name and type. This function can be used to load these settings as an array along with the field’s value.

So `get_field_object('icon')['ID'])` doesn't return the ID of image attachment, but ID of that ACF field.

What you want to use is:

```
$var = get_children(array(
    'exclude' => array(
        get_post_thumbnail_id(),
        get_field('icon')
    )
));
```

If your field returns the ID of selected image, or

```
$image = get_field('icon');
$var = get_children(array(
    'exclude' => array(
        get_post_thumbnail_id(),
        $image['ID']
    )
));
```

if it returns an array.

[More on `get_field` for Image field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Comment: Hey, there! Thanks. I want to return the ID of the image attached to that post via ACF, just like `get_post_thumbnail_id()` returns the ID of the post thumbnail. I have tried both options you've presented before trying to combine both, haha, but none work.

Comment: @LuizCruz it all depends on how your field is defined and what are its settings set to...

Comment: probably. Isn't an ID set for every attachment?

Comment: @LuizCruz every attachment has an ID. But the ACF image field can have different result format (ID or array). But ACF is third party plugin and as such it’s off topic on this site. So from WP point of view everything should be fine if you’ll get the ID correctly. You should use one of ways from my answer - and read the article on Image field (link at the end of answer).

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean and the difference between functions `get_field_object()` and `get_field()`. I'll try to figure something out. Thanks!

Comment: I understood what was wrong. The return value for icon was set as URL (because I used it like that somewhere else). I changed it to return the ID and adapted that other function to keep working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. I’m glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The ACF function returns an array, so would this work?

```
$field_object = get_field_object('icon'); // add post id as 2nd param if needed
$var = get_children( 
  array(
  'exclude' => array(
    get_post_thumbnail_id(),
    $field_object['value'] // the saved value of the field, type cast to int if needed
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work, because it isn't even a correct PHP code - it will cause syntax error.

Comment: Just a sec, I'll fix it. Apparently trying to writing code on mobile isn't a great idea.

Comment: Yeah, writing code on mobile is really hard sometimes... :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I also thought this would work but it doesn't. For some reason it won't read the result of `$field_object['value']` correctly.

Comment: Interesting, I was just working with the same function earlier today with no problems. Does the `get_field_object()` return anything at all? Would explicitly setting the post id make it work?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I've tried using `$post->ID` but I get the same result :(